# Trying to share a question with Facebook: Outcome quite unexpected

Tags: bug, status-declined, sharing, facebook

So I tried to share this innocent enough question with Facebook: [Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/1461424)

And this is what popped up:

[image: Wat?]

And indeed, the shared post directs me to a particularly disturbing article with the same title in `gawker.com`.

I checked the meta tags in page source, but to my knowledge there are no open graph (`og`) tags hinting this slightly surprising title.

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="stackoverflow.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6" />
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?" />
<meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="I am having some difficulty compiling a C++ program that I&#39;ve written.

This program is very simple and, to the best of my knowledge, conforms to all the rules set forth in the C++ Standard.  I&#39;ve ..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers"/>
```

Could this be a Facebook bug, or is Stack Overflow messing with Facebook's crawlers?

Comment: I don't know, but I like it! :)

Comment: I did a view-source on the question you linked and I could not find that text anywhere in the source. **However** SO seems to have a CSS class called *.ice-ice-baby*.

Comment: THIS. IS. AWESOME.

Comment: So *that's* why my code isn't compiling.

Comment: See, this is why proof-reading is helpful.

Comment: Note to self: don't ever piss off a baby in Pakistan.

Comment: +1, can reproduce this.

Comment: Happy Halloween!

Comment: Well, either something should be done about sharing links on facebook from stackoverflow, or about babies in Pakistan.. one of the two.

Comment: Perhaps you had something else in your paste buffer?

Comment: Gawker really would do anything for clicks...

Comment: Even if the issue is somewhat solved (it still posts the correct title as demonstrated in the answer below) I'd love to know what causes it...

Comment: Maybe a hash conflict somewhere in the depths of Facebook's sharing code?  They must generate and store the thumbnails and snippets somewhere on their server, probably with a hashed version of the URL as an identifier.

Comment: Wow. What's with that page? I loaded it and my RAM usage went up to ~88% with ~47% swap to boot. And Chrome tried to kill the tab concerned.<(O.o)>

Comment: One more in a long list of reasons why Faecesbook should be removed from existence.

Comment: @ivarni That's to ensure that people stop, collaborate and listen.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this, but actually posting the question fixed the issue, causing the correct title to show:

[image]

Comment: curiously, if I click the little arrow in the top right, it gives me the option to "Save Baby Accused of Murder Plot..."

Comment: Well...were you able to save the baby?

Answer (score 38):

Facebook seems to have fixed this, but I was able to take a picture before they did!

[image]

Comment: Well done, soldier.  You're bound to receive the medal of honor for this.